# Filter elements from array based on a field using $nin condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo document like below;

```
{
    "_id": "123",
    "name": "ABC",
    "elements": {
        "_id": "123",
        "minorElements": [
            [
                {
                    "id": "xyz1",
                    "name": "xyz1"
                }, {
                    "id": "xyz2",
                    "name": "xyz2"
                }, {
                    "id": "xyz3",
                    "name": "xyz3"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "id": "xyz1",
                    "name": "xyz1"
                }, {
                    "id": "xyz3",
                    "name": "xyz3"
                }, {
                    "id": "xyz5",
                    "name": "xyz5"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

"elements.minorElements" is an array of array.

How can I write a mongo aggregation to remove objects from "elements.minorElements" where "id" not in "xyz1" and "xyz2"?

Expected output:

```
{
    "_id": "123",
    "name": "ABC",
    "elements": {
        "_id": "123",
        "minorElements": [
            [{
                    "id": "xyz1",
                    "name": "xyz1"
                }, {
                    "id": "xyz2",
                    "name": "xyz2"
                }
            ],
            [{
                    "id": "xyz1",
                    "name": "xyz1"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

sample payload https://mongoplayground.net/p/9RjC6GzSQDQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) for outer array and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) for inner array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            "elements.minorElements": {
                $map: {
                    input: "$elements.minorElements",
                    as: "me",
                    in: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: "$$me",
                            cond: {
                                $in: [ "$$this.id", [ "xyz1", "xyz2" ] ]
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DKGew1OG276)

Answer (score 2):

2 points to notice :
First,

> to remove objects from "elements.minorElements" where "id" not in "xyz1" and "xyz2"

=> simply means that you need to keep (project) elements where id is "xyz1" or "xyz2" (or id in ["xyz1", "xyz2"])

Second,

As you noticed, "elements.minorElements" is an array of array. So, when you apply your $filter operator, you try to apply it **on an array**.

The tip is to apply a $map operator for the first level of array, and then a $fiter operator on each element of $map.

Here's the query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "elements.minorElements": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$elements.minorElements",
          "as": "item",
          "in": {
            $filter: {
              input: "$$item",
              as: "subItem",
              cond: {
                $in: [
                  "$$subItem.id",
                  [
                    "xyz1",
                    "xyz2"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          },

        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[You can test it here.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oqJwp3QbXkK)